# gwt-google-apis call results in "Cannot call method 'newHttpRequest' of undefined"

Tags: java, gwt, google-plus

I am using the gwt-plus-v1-0.2-alpha API to:

1. Allow Google login
2. Fetch Signed in user's information

Google login works, but fetching the user's information fails with a

```
Cannot call method 'newHttpRequest' of undefined
```

error.

The following is my `GoogleApi` helper class:

```
public final class GoogleApi {
    private static final Plus plus = GWT.create(Plus.class);

    private final String clientId;

    private final ClientOAuth2Login oAuth2Login;
    private ClientGoogleApiRequestTransport requestTransport;

    /**
     * @param clientId
     *            This app's personal client ID assigned by the Google APIs
     *            Console (http://code.google.com/apis/console)
     */
    public GoogleApi(EventBus eventBus, String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
        requestTransport = new ClientGoogleApiRequestTransport();
        requestTransport.setApplicationName(MY_APP_NAME)
                .setApiAccessKey(MY_API_KEY);
        plus.initialize(eventBus, requestTransport);
        oAuth2Login = new ClientOAuth2Login(clientId);
        oAuth2Login.withScopes(PlusAuthScope.PLUS_ME);
    }

    public void login(final Receiver<String> callback) {
        oAuth2Login.login(new Receiver<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                requestTransport.setAccessToken(response);
                callback.onSuccess(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(ServerFailure error) {
                Window.alert(error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    public void getUserInfo(Receiver<Person> receiver) {
        plus.people().get("me").to(receiver).fire();
    }
}
```

The following shows where the failure occurs:

```
GoogleApi googleApi = new GoogleApi(eventBus, MY_CLIENT_ID);

googleApi.login(new Receiver<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(final String token) {
        // login is successful and access token is received

        // but the following call fails with "Cannot call method 'newHttpRequest'
        // of undefined" error
        googleApi.getUserInfo(new Receiver<Person>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Person person) {
                // never gets here
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(ServerFailure error) {
                // nor here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try updating your gwt-google-apis libraries, there's been a change back in June that replaced calls to `$wnd.googleapis.newHttpRequest()` with calls to `$wnd.gapi.client.rpcRequest()`: https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/source/detail?r=2041

The reason authentication works it that it doesn't use the same code to talk to the server.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Thomas.  Is there a downloadable jar that contains these latest changes?  The most recent [gwt-plus jar](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/downloads/list?can=1&q=plus&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount) that I can find is v1.0.3 dating back to March.

Comment: I couldn't get the latest version of the API to work, so I'm going to have to use the code that I pasted in my own answer along with gwt-plus-v1.0.2-alpha.jar

Answer (score 1):

I have played around with the code (still using version 1.0.2-alpha) and made it work!  The following is the updated code:

```
public final class GoogleApi {
    private static final Plus plus = GWT.create(Plus.class);

    private final String clientId;

    private EventBus eventBus;

    private final ClientOAuth2Login oAuth2Login;
    private ClientGoogleApiRequestTransport requestTransport;

    private String accessToken;

    /**
     * @param clientId
     *            This app's personal client ID assigned by the Google APIs
     *            Console (http://code.google.com/apis/console)
     */
    public GoogleApi(final EventBus eventBus, String clientId) {
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
        this.clientId = clientId;
        oAuth2Login = new ClientOAuth2Login(clientId);
        oAuth2Login.withScopes(PlusAuthScope.PLUS_ME);
    }

    public void login(final Receiver<String> callback) {
        oAuth2Login.login(new Receiver<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                accessToken = response;
                callback.onSuccess(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(ServerFailure error) {
                Window.alert(error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    public void getUserInfo(final Receiver<Person> receiver) {
        requestTransport = new ClientGoogleApiRequestTransport();
        requestTransport.setApplicationName(ClientConstants.GOOGLE_APP_NAME)
                .setApiAccessKey(ClientConstants.GOOGLE_API_KEY)
                .setAccessToken(accessToken);
        requestTransport.create(new Receiver<GoogleApiRequestTransport>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(GoogleApiRequestTransport transport) {
                plus.initialize(eventBus, transport);
                plus.people().get("me").to(receiver).fire();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I don't know how efficient this is, though.  A call to Plus's initialize() method is made every time a call to getUserInfo() is made.

Next step for me is to manually build a jar with the latest version of the API and adjust my code accordingly :/  Wish me luck!